# Не копировать css файлы с префиксом

Tags: css, gulp, postcss

Использую PostCss вместе с Gulp.
Плагин для postcss - precss.
Подключаю в css файлы с помощью @import, все подключаемые файлы имеют префикс "_" например "_meida.css". Как можно сделать, чтобы при компиляции файлы с префиксом не копировались в исходную директорию.

Например есть следующие файлы:

```
/style
..style.css
.._media.css
```

В исходной папке должно быть так:

```
/css
..style.css
```

Код gulp

```
    gulp.task('css', function() {
    var plugins = [
        precss(),
        //cssnext()
    ];

    gulp.src('app/style/**/*.css')
        .pipe(postcss(plugins))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
});
```